# WKInterfaceInlineMovie Starts Playing Even if setAutoplays(_:) is Set to false

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I have an `WKInterfaceInlineMovie` within an `WKInterfaceController`. The URL of the video is set at some point after the video file is downloaded. Playing works fine besides [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62451605/watchkit-wkinterfaceinlinemovie-pause-rewinds-video-to-the-beginning) which is a different story, I think.

**Here's the problem.** If I keep the screen open, lower my wrist and then raise it again, I can see the same screen and the video starts playing automatically.

It looks very weird and unexpected especially because I have some custom UI (video progress indicator, animated Play/Pause buttons) which is triggered when I manually start the video but it obviously doesn't react on this unwanted automatic video start. If I close the extension with the Crown button, next time I open the app, it again shows the screen with video and start playing automatically. I can even not using the extension for a while and receive a user notification later – while the custom notification UI is displayed, I can hear the video starts playing somewhere below for a short period of time.

When it happens I always receive two messages in console:

```
<<<< PlayerRemoteXPC >>>> remoteXPCPlaybackItem_NotificationFilter: [0x128b86e0] I/NQB.01 Received kFigPlaybackItemNotification_FirstVideoFrameEnqueued
<<<< PlayerRemoteXPC >>>> remoteXPCItem_handleFirstFrameNotificationLatch: [0x128b86e0] I/NQB.01 Posting kFigPlaybackItemNotification_FirstVideoFrameEnqueued
```

I have the Autoplay checkmark unchecked in storyboard. I also tried to set `setAutoplays(_:)` to `false` programmatically when the outlet is initialized, or later when a URL is set to the movie. All of this makes no difference.

The behavior is the same no matter was the video playing or not when the screen get deactivated. I tried to call `pause()` on `willDisappear()` and `didDeactivate()` – it also doesn't do any difference.

I even tried to call `pause()` on `didAppear()` and `willActivate()` – didn't help either. Curiously enough, these methods are not called when I lower the wrist and raise it again  (however, `willDisappear()` and `didDeactivate()` are both called.) But perhaps, [it's a different story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66815680/wkinterfacecontroller-lifecycle-when-the-wrist-is-lowered-raised), too.